# Opening ChatApplication in a Pop Up Window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drupal, popup, chat

I'm working on this project website wherein i will be adding a chat application where users can communicate with each other. I already have developed a chat room webpage which is now functioning well. However, what I want is to create a "Chat Room" link on my website which will just pop out the chat room as a pop-up window upon click.

Can somebody please help me on how to do this? Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you link to the chat room has `target = "_blank"`, it will open in a new window:

```
<a href="chatroom">opens inline</a>

<a href="chatroom" target="_blank">opens in a new window</a>
```

This is just normal HTML / browser behavior.